# How to use split function in node js

Tags: node.js, mqtt, node-modules

I have combined two strings at the client side to publish on a topic

```
client.publish(topic,payload = String(message)+","+String(weather))
```

I receive them at the server side as a string
But this are two different messages which I have to send at two different http address 
I want to split the message at the server end 
But the split function is not working

> This is the error message.
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

---

```
//MQTT publisher

var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var fetch = require('node-fetch')
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1884')
var topic = 'local/temperature'
//var message = 'The status of weather station'

client.on('connect',()=>{

setInterval(async function(req,res){
        let weatherResponse = await fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=villingen-schwenningen,de&units=metric&appid=4b66b441cf82f4bca0467ecebb363a79");
        let weatherObj = await weatherResponse.json()
        let temperature = weatherObj.main.temp
        let message = JSON.stringify(temperature)
        let weather = JSON.stringify(weatherObj)
        client.publish(topic,payload = String(message)+","+String(weather))
        console.log(payload)
        console.log('Temperature value sent!')
        console.log('The temperature is',message)
    },3000)
})

//MQTT server (mosca broker)

const mosca = require("mosca")

var temperature = 0; 

moscaSettings = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 1884,
    persistence: { factory: mosca.persistence.Memory }
}

var server = new mosca.Server(moscaSettings);

server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
    console.log('client connected', client.id);
});
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
    console.log('Published', packet.payload.toString());
    // I want to split the payload here 
    //console.log(info);
});
server.on('ready', setup);
function setup() {
    console.log('Mosca server is up and running on port '+ moscaSettings.port);
}
```

Comment: Using the `split()` function isn't the problem. The fact that the value you are trying to split is `undefined` is the problem. There's nothing in your post that can tell us why that's happening.

Comment: Please show the line of code that is directly responsible for the error message.  The one line you show now does not even attempt to use a `.split` property so it's hard to see how it could be the one responsible.